# Calculate difference of two xts time series when values are at different times

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I have two xts time series in R and want to calculate the differences between the values of the time series at the times which are closest to each other. That is, if my two indices are:

```
[1] (10/10/05 13:00:00) (10/10/05 14:00:00) (10/10/05 14:23:00)
```

and

```
[1] (10/10/05 12:38:00) (10/10/05 12:53:00) (10/10/05 12:59:00) (10/10/05 13:08:00) (10/10/05 13:23:00)
[6] (10/10/05 13:38:00) (10/10/05 13:53:00) (10/10/05 14:23:00) (10/10/05 15:05:00) (10/10/05 15:11:00)
```

I want to calculate the differences of the values at:

- 13:00 and 12:59
- 14:00 and 13:53
- 14:30 and 14:23

How should I do this? The standard `merge` method from `zoo` with `all=FALSE` won't do what I want because the indices have to be exactly equal for it to merge properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide a reproducible example, so I can't give you a specific solution.  Generally, you can use `align.time` to change the index values of each object to a similar periodicity, or you could merge and use `na.locf` to fill the missing values.  Then you can do whatever operations you want between the two series.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've tried using `align.time` but that seems to require a number of seconds to align to (eg. `60*60` to align to every hour) whereas I want to align to the times in another array.

`na.locf` seems useful - but it will only carry forward the last observation, whereas I want the closest observation (eg. if I want value at 13:00, and last observation is at 12:30 and next observation is at 13:01 I want the 13:01 value). Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I would have to think about that... I seem to remember someone asking a very similar question, but I can't remember if it was on SO or R-SIG-Finance.  A small example data set and your desired output would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking about something like this: for each member of the first series, you insert it in the second series according to their time index and then compute the absolute differences between the indices of the inserted first series member and that of the preceding and following second series members, taking the corresponding difference between values for which the absolute difference between indices is the smallest.